# What is the correct rotation at a AVL Tree after an insert?

Tags: insert, rotation, avl-tree

At this excercise, why is a double `rotation` made in this `AVL` Tree after the insert(2) ?
[image]

I thought since the Tree ist `-1/+2` (from `5` and `3`) and both balance values are negative a simple `rotation` should be made. But a double `rotation` is made.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the example tree with the balance factors below the relevant nodes:

[image]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Rebalancing) explains how rebalancing is achieved:

> Let X be the node that has a (temporary) balance factor of −2 or +2. Its left or right subtree was modified. Let Z be the higher child (see figures 2 and 3).

In the example at hand,  is thus the node with value 3, and  is the node with value 1. Here is the image with those labels added (also ):

[image]

The Wikipedia article states:

> In case of insertion this insertion has happened to one of Z's children in a way that Z's height has increased.

We can confirm this, as the inserted value was 2.

We then read:

> There are four possible variants of the violation:
>
> - Right Right ⟹ Z is a *right*    child of its parent X and BF(Z) ≥ 0
> - Left Left   ⟹ Z is a *left* child of its parent X and BF(Z) ≤ 0
> - Right Left  ⟹ Z is a *right*    child of its parent X and BF(Z) < 0
> - Left Right  ⟹ Z is a *left* child of its parent X and BF(Z) > 0

In your example tree we are in the last case.

The Wikipedia article then indicates which rotation(s) are needed. For that last case, the action to perform is:

> Left Right    ⟹ X is rebalanced with a    double  rotation `rotate_LeftRight` (mirror-image of figure 3)

So the double rotation is expected here.